# Как очистить QLineEdit при клике по нему?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `lineEdit` нужно сделать так что бы при клике на него он сбрасывался, и  можно было бы вводить новый текст в него.

Вот мой пример, но тут проблема, я хочу сделать по одному клику, а получается только со 2-го.

```
connect::(ui->lineEdit_password, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(clearPassword()));

void MainWindow::clearPassword()
{
    ui->lineEdit_password->clear();
    ui->lineEdit_password->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::PasswordEchoOnEdit);
    ui->lineEdit_password->setReadOnly(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переопределить mousePressEvent.

```
#include <QLineEdit>

class LineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
public:
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QLineEdit(parent)
    {}
protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* /*event*/)
    {
        clear();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте переопределить `focusInEvent`

```
#include <QLineEdit>

class LineEdit : public QLineEdit{
public:
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QLineEdit(parent)
    {}
protected:
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event){
        clear();
        QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

[QWidget::mousePressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)

[QLineEdit::clear](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#clear)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Копипаста знаний так же не добавляет, но при этом подвержена устареванию и не дает полной картины.

Comment: Копирование – не добавляет, рекомендации основанные на личной экспертизе – уникальные в большинстве случаев. Уверен, автор вопроса может легко найти ответ, состоящий из ссылок, в любом поисковике.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Личную экспертизу лучше сводить к минимуму, если есть подробная документация по этому вопросу (буквально). Задача ресурса - помочь вопрошающему найти ответ, что я и сделал. Возможно, стоило словами подчеркнуть связь метода и события, но это уж никак не тянет на даунвоут.

Comment: В системе [не приветствуются ответы–ссылки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/6).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Это я заметил. Но я помогаю конкретному человеку, с конкретной проблемой, а не системе. И отдельно взятый модератор пытается мешать мне это делать, потому что у него есть флейм на мете.

Comment: Ну Вы могли бы рассписать ответ подробнее, что и как нужно использовать, а не просто вбить две ссылки. Я не ставил Вам минусов, но они вполне оправданы. Да, кстати, Nicolas не простой модератор, а [community manager](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do)

Comment: @ixSci Для этого есть менее радиакальные способы - прокомментировать с просьбой или поправить самому. Даунвоут был бы актуален, если ответ полностью бесполезен. Это относится к любому участнику сообщества, а отношение этого модератора к системе лишь увеличивает мою боль по этому поводу.